# Struts2 - Repopulating a page with updated data after form submit

Tags: struts2

I have a jsp page called diary.jsp where the action class associated with it is called DiaryAction and in this class I am using the populate method to prepopulate fields. This is working as expected when I first access the page using PopulateDiary.action in the URL i.e.

```
<li><a href="populateDiary.action">Profile</a></li>
```

However as part of this page I have a form where a user can add a new diary entry. On the submit of this form I call the following action:

```
<action name="addDiaryEntry" method="addDiaryEntry"    
    class="spirit.of.community.action.classes.DiaryAction">
    <result name="success">/diary.jsp</result>
</action>
```

This is calling the correct code to add the new diary entry. However, on the success of this action method I want to display the same page i.e diary.jsp with the populated data again (to include the updated entry). I have placed this line inside my diary.jsp page in the hope that this would accomplish my goal:

```
<s:action name="populateDiary"></s:action>
```

Now when the diary.jsp loads I can see the populate method being called. But the page isn't populated with any of my data. If its of any importance, the URL when the form is submitted is - "/addDiaryEntry.action". Can anyone advise how I could call my addEvent method to add a new entry, and then reload the page with the updated data? Any advice is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have few ways to accomplish this and here they are

1. When you call `addDiaryEntry` action to add a diary instance you can create a list of all entries and can make use of iterator to show the data as per your way.
2. Other way is to `<s:action name="populateDiary" executeResult="true">`.

execute result tell whether the result of this action (probably a view) should be executed/rendered.

For more details refer to the [Execute action](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/action.html)